# ServiceStack 4 compatible Server Sent Events Client for .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, servicestack, server-sent-events

Is there any solution available to communicate with the great Server Side Event (SSE) system implemented in ServiceStack 4 from within a .NET 3.5 client environment?

Maybe there's some different client implementation available?

The ServiceStack 4 [ServerEventsClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-Server-Events-Client) and its dependencies like ServiceStack.Text make excessive use of .NET 4.0 features like System.Dynamic, which can only be made .NET 3.5 compatible with huge efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to enable support for .NET 3.5+. The **ServiceStack.Text** and **ServiceStack.Client** projects would need to be back ported so that it builds in .NET 3.5 with any .NET 4.0 features removed or **#if/defined** out.

Comment: Yes, tried that but stopped (early enough). Do you know of any other existing clients which can/could communicate with the SS SSE backend?

Comment: @derFunk No, I'm not aware of any SSE C# Clients that target .NET 3.5.

Comment: Although I've not tested if this works with ServiceStack, the Unity Plugin "BestHttp" supports Server-Sent Events, thus being compatible to .Net 3.5, it might be usable standalone as well. See https://docs.google.com/document/d/181l8SggPrVF1qRoPMEwobN_1Fn7NXOu-VtfjE6wvokg/edit#heading=h.1t7n04on9n62